# How can I download the Schema from a PostgreSQL db hosted on heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, backup, database-schema

I would like to create a ERM-Diagram from a PostgreSQL Database which is hosted on heroku. 
The database itself is almost 20 GB big, which makes downloading the whole dump not an option.

Is there a way to simply backup and download the schema including foreign keys, and maybe 10 rows of each table in the database, which could subsequently be restored into a local dabase via the `psql`-command?

I have the [PG Backups Plus](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups) addon enabled, but that seems to only enable me to dump the whole database with the complete dataset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use pg_dump instead. The `--schema-only|-s` option does just what you're looking for.

```
pg_dump --schema-only -h host -U user -f schema_dump_file dbname
```

Then just manually grab a bit of data that you want. There's no easy way, that I know of or seen, around that.